# Convert a JSON to a required format in type script

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular5

I am very new to Angualr 6 and type script. From backend API call I am getting data in below format.

```
> res = [{
>     "metadata": {
>         "lastGpSyncTime": "2000-11-21T16:07:53",
>         "dataFromDB": true
>     },
>     "noGoalSelectionReport": {
>         "userCount": 0
>     },
>     "oneGoalSelectionReport": {
>         "userCount": 237
>     },
>     "twoGoalSelectionReport": {
>         "userCount": 176
>     },
>     "threeGoalSelectionReport": {
>         "userCount": 17
>     },
>     "registeredCount": 547 }];
```

I need to convert it to in such a format so that I can display it in a bar chart. Bar chart requires below format.

```
[{
  "goalName": "No Goal",
  "userCount": 0
}, {
  "goalName": "One Goal",
  "userCount": 237
}, {
  "goalName": "Two Goals",
  "userCount": 176
}, {
  "goalName": "Three Goals",
  "userCount": 17
}];
```

How can I do that using type script.

Comment: Typescript is more or less just type annotations. It can not convert json formats itself. But Javascript can. You should process it via plain js statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about ?

```
    formatData(res): { goalName: string, userCount: number }[] {

        const data = res[0];
        const groupNames = Object.keys(data);

        const formattedData = [];

        groupNames.forEach(groupName => {
            if (groupName !== 'metadata') {

                // Add Space before capital letter and remove SelectionReport
                let goalName = groupName.replace('SelectionReport', '').replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim();

                // Capitalize first letter
                goalName = goalName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + goalName.slice(1);

                const dataGroupFormatted = {
                    goalName,
                    userCount: data[groupName].userCount
                };

                formattedData.push(dataGroupFormatted);
            }
        });

        return formattedData;

    }
```

The power of Typescript is to define type, here for example your bar chart requires a specific type which is an array of objects containing a goalName and a userCount. You can improve my answer by adding more type (for example the input type for res).

Answer (score 0):

An easy examle

```
    var result = Object.keys(this.res[0]);
    let temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i] !== "metadata" && result[i] !== "registeredCount") {
        
        temp.push({
          userCount: this.res[0][result[i]].userCount,
          goalName:
            result[i]
              .toUpperCase()
              .charAt(0) +
            result[i]
              .replace("SelectionReport", "")
              .replace(/([A-Z])/g, " $1")
              .trim()
              .slice(1)
        });
      }
    }
    console.log(temp);
```